# Pass from filter's frequency response to time-domain [b, a] representation

Tags: python, scipy, filtering, signal-processing

FIR and IIR filters are usually defined by [b, a] coefficients in time-domain regression formula:

```
y[n] = b_0 * x[n] + b_1 * x[n-1] + ... + b_N * x[n - N] - a_1 * y[n-1] - ... - a_M * y[n-M]
```

One can extract the frequency response `h` from `[b,a]` using Fourier Transform or use the built-in `scipy` function `signal.freqz`:

```
w, h = signal.freqz(b, a, worN=FFT_LENGTH, fs=FS)
```

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.freqz.html

My question is how to go the other way around. Assuming I get a frequency response `h(w)` generated by `freqz` or `fft` of `[b, a]`, how to recover those `[b, a]` so I can apply the filter in time-domain using `signal.lfilter` for example?

I am aware that this problem may have no general solution and that inverse may not exist.

Added in Edit:

In the case of FIR I think one can do FFT, because basically: `h = fft(b)`. In IIR case `h = fft(b)/fft(a)` so it might not work.

Comment: Turning a high order FIR into an IIR is a non-trivial problem. What order are your FIR and II filters ? How did you generate the original IIR filter coefficients ?